# not getting proper date while parsing String date to Date

Tags: java

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yy-mm-dd");
formatter.setLenient(false);
String[] dateStr = { "2013-12-27", "2013-01-03"};
for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
     Date date = formatter.parse(dateStr[i]);
     System.out.println("date is "+date);
}
```

result :
Sun Jan 27 00:12:00 IST 2013

Thu Jan 03 00:01:00 IST 2013

i am parsing string date in to Date.but it is giving me date Starting with month Jan regardless of what month i am passing to formatter constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format for your date would be `yy-MM-dd`. Update your format and check.

Comment: A [link to the relevant documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) would make this answer even better.

Answer (score 4):

`mm` for **minutes**
`MM` for **month**

Use: "yy-MM-dd"

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 3):

once Silly Mistake

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd");
```

Format this line in your code

Comment: thank you Goutam..actually i was using formatter but the problem was with java.utill.date class when i tried to get date using date class it was giving me wrong date.. but when i used java.sql.date class it worked.